# any way to avoid duplicate code while writing asyc code in vertx?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am writing functions like these and I have a couple of them. if we see the response handler in both of them are same lines of code.

```
private void get(JsonObject request, Message<JsonObject> message) {

    webClient.get(webClientPort,
            webClientHost, "/document/" + request.getString("key"))
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
            .send(res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) {
                    message.reply(res.result().bodyAsString());
                } else {
                    message.fail(0, Json.encode(new JsonObject().put("error", res.cause())));
                }
            });

}


private void add(JsonObject request, Message<JsonObject> message) {

    webClient.post(webClientPort,
            webClientHost, "/document/" + request.getString("key"))
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
            .sendJson(request.getJsonObject("document").encodePrettily(), res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) {
                    message.reply(res.result().bodyAsString());
                } else {
                    message.fail(0, Json.encode(new JsonObject().put("error", res.cause())));
                }
            });

}
```

is there a way to avoid this duplicate code and move it to a common place?

```
res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) {
                    message.reply(res.result().bodyAsString());
                } else {
                    message.fail(0, Json.encode(new JsonObject().put("error", res.cause())));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do like this and it worked. Thanks @dovmo for your help. your inputs helped me reached to solution.

```
private void get(String key, Message<JsonObject> message) {
    webClient.get(webClientPort,
            webClientHost, "/document/" + key)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
            .send(processResponse(message));
}

private void delete(String key, JsonObject body, Message<JsonObject> message) {
    webClient.delete(webClientPort,
            webClientHost, "/document/" + key)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
            .send(processResponse(message));
}

private Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<Buffer>>> processResponse( Message<JsonObject> message) {

    Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<Buffer>>> handler = reply -> {
        if (reply.succeeded()) {
            message.reply(reply.result().bodyAsString());
        } else {
            message.fail(0, Json.encode(new JsonObject().put("error", reply.cause())));
        }
    };

    return handler;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just encapsulate that logic another function and call it via method reference?

```
private void processResponse(HttpServerResponse res, Message<JsonObject> message) {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
        message.reply(res.result().bodyAsString());
    } else {
        message.fail(0, Json.encode(new JsonObject().put("error", res.cause())));
    }
}
```

Then you can just call it with a method reference in both places your code:

```
.send(res -> this.processResponse(res, message));
```

and

```
.sendJson(request.getJsonObject("document").encodePrettily(), res -> this.processResponse(res, message));
```

Comment: I thought about that but `message` is not accessible in new method

Comment: Ah, ok, I edited the post. Similarly, you can still invoke the method with another argument

Comment: the code which we are trying to move is a handler to `send` and `sendJson`.  following is the declaration of the functions `void send(Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<T>>> var1);` and `void sendJson(Object var1, Handler<AsyncResult<HttpResponse<T>>> var2);`